# How to add 'Windows Explorer' to the 'Open with' context menu, in Eclipse Development

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm an eclipse plugin developer, actually new to it. 
The background is, when I right click on a project resource files or a folder, I should a have an option 'Windows Explorer' under 'Open With' context menu. So, that when I do this the linked resource is opened in windows explorer. How to acheive this programatically.

Comment: The 'Open With' menu does not support folders at all and will only show Eclipse editors for files. You would probably be better off coding your own menu item.

Comment: Thanks Greg :) and it also would make sense to have in a different menu rather than adding to 'Open With' menu.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly inside the "Open with" option, but you have the same functionality using EasyShell plugin for Eclipse.

Have a look at that:

https://anb0s.github.io/EasyShell/